# identify clicked component among same components

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><div><svg><path></path></svg></div><span>Text 1</span></li>
  <li><div><svg><path></path></svg></div><span>Text 2</span></li>
  <li><div><svg><path></path></svg></div><span>Text 3</span></li>
</ul>
```

what I want is when I click I can get the `<li>` element, but when I try e.targer I get the `<span>,<path>,<div>` and `<li>` from different click areas. So what should I do to get the `<li>` element.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding event listeners to your li element will work here. Have you tried attaching onClick event handler on li tag.
For eg in functional components:-

```
const [state, setState] = useState('');
function handleClick(event) {
   setState(event.target.id);
}


<li id="3" onClick={handleClick}>Demo</li>
```

Comment: I did attaching onClick event handler on li tag but the result is what I said before.

Comment: @osamu1908, can you jsfiddle linl for ur code snippet here